# Difference between logarithm of an expectation value and expectation value of a logarithm

Tags: probability, random, parameter-estimation

Assuming I have a always positive random variable $X$, $X \in \mathbb{R}$, $X > 0$. Then  I am now interested in the difference between the following two expectation values:

1. $E \left[ \ln X \right]$
2. $\ln E \left[ X \right]$

Is one maybe always a lower/upper bound of the other?

Many thanks in advance...

Comment: Just thought I'd add a link to a [near identical question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38296/expected-value-of-a-natural-logarithm) over on CrossValidated.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Since the function logarithm is concave, [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) shows that $E(\ln(X))\leqslant \ln E(X)$ and that equality occurs iff $X$ is almost surely constant.

---

**Edit** (This is to expand on a remark made by Shai.)

Shai's answer explains how to prove $E(\ln(X))\leqslant \ln E(X)$ using only AM-GM inequality and the strong law of large numbers. These very tools yield the following refinement (adapted from the paper [Self-improvement of the inequality between arithmetic and geometric means](http://jmi.ele-math.com/03-21) by J. M. Aldaz).

Apply AM-GM inequality to the *square roots* of an i.i.d. sequence of positive random variables $(X_i)$, that is,
$$
\sqrt[n]{\sqrt{X_1}\cdots\sqrt{X_n}}\leqslant\frac1n(\sqrt{X_1}+\cdots+\sqrt{X_n}).
$$
In the limit $n\to\infty$, the strong law of large numbers yields
$$
\exp(E(\ln\sqrt{X}))\leqslant E(\sqrt{X}),
$$
that is,
$$
E(\ln X)\leqslant 2\ln E(\sqrt{X})=\ln (E(X)-\mbox{var}(\sqrt{X})).
$$
Finally:

> For every positive integrable $X$, 
>   $$
> E(\ln X)\leqslant [\ln E(X)]-\delta(X)\quad\mbox{where}\ \delta(X)=\ln[E(X)/E(\sqrt{X})^2].
> $$

The correction term $\delta(X)$ is nonnegative for every $X$, and $\delta(X)=0$ iff $X$ is almost surely constant.

Naturally, this also obtains directly through Jensen's inequality applied to $\sqrt{X}$.

And this result is just a special case of the fact that, for every $s$ in $(0,1)$,
$$
E(\ln X)\leqslant [\ln E(X)]-\delta_s(X)\quad\mbox{where}\ \delta_s(X)=\ln[E(X)/E(X^s)^{1/s}].
$$
The quantity $\delta_s(X)$ is a nonincreasing function of $s$ hence the upper bound $[\ln E(X)]-\delta_s(X)$ is better and better when $s$ decreases to $0$. For every $X$, $\delta_1(X)=0$, $\delta_{1/2}(X)=\delta(X)$ and $\delta_0(X)=[\ln E(X)]-E(\ln X)$.

The interesting point in all this, if any, is that one has *quantified* the discrepancy between $E(\ln X)$ and $\ln E(X)$ and, simultaneously, recovered the fact that $E(\ln X)=\ln E(X)$ iff $X$ is almost surely constant.

Comment: I didn't expect such a complete and neat answer in such a short time...

Comment: @Shai: Well, once you had pointed me in the right direction... Thanks again for the reference to Aldaz's paper.

Comment: Can you provide a mathematical definition for "$X$ is almost surely constant"?

Comment: @NalRa Yes I can. And you?

Comment: @Did I want to show when $X=1+v^2$, where $v$ is Gaussian distributed with mean $m$ and variance $\sigma^2$, the $E(\ln X) \rightarrow \ln E(X)$ as m approaches to infinity and $\sigma$ remains a constant. I wonder whether this $X$ satisfies your definition about "surely constant"

Comment: @NalRa If this is your problem, I suggest to ask it as a separate question instead of obliquely (and rather incomprehensibly) commenting on old unrelated answers.

Comment: @Did Oh, yes! I will make a try.

Answer (score 10):

To add on Didier's answer, it is instructive to note that the inequality ${\rm E}(\ln X) \le \ln {\rm E}(X)$
can be seen as a consequence of the [AM-GM inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) combined with the [strong law of large numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers), upon writing 
the AM-GM inequality
$$
\sqrt[n]{{X_1  \cdots X_n }} \le \frac{{X_1  +  \cdots  + X_n }}{n}
$$
as
$$
\exp \bigg(\frac{{\ln X_1  +  \cdots  + \ln X_n }}{n}\bigg) \le \frac{{X_1  +  \cdots  + X_n }}{n},
$$
and letting $n \to \infty$.

EDIT: For completeness, let me note that ${\rm E}[\ln X]$ might be equal to $-\infty$. For example, if $X$ has density function 
$$
f(x) = \frac{{\ln a}}{{x\ln ^2 x}},\;\;0 < x < \frac{1}{a},
$$
where $a>1$ (note that $\int f  = 1$), then 
$$
{\rm E}[\ln X] = 
\int_0^{1/a} {\frac{{\ln a}}{{x\ln x}}} \,{\rm d}x = -\infty.
$$

Comment: Nice. I have always wondered whether AM-GM also proved the equality case, maybe you know the answer.

Comment: @Didier: Interesting question. It seems that a partial answer can be deduced from Theorem 1 in http://files.ele-math.com/articles/jmi-03-21.pdf (by letting $\alpha_i = 1/n$).

Comment: Thanks, I added an explanation of this to my answer.